# firebase navigates to sign in activity while switching activity inside a home activity

Tags: java, android, firebase

I've done my Firebase Authentication which signs in user and navigates him to HomeActivity. This works but then when I try to move from the Home Activity to the next one it navigates me back to the MainActivity (which in this case is Sign In).

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btnSearch;
    private TextView welcomeLbl;
    private Button btnSignout;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        welcomeLbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeLbl);
        btnSignout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignout) ;

        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignout.setOnClickListener(this);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {

            Intent signInIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(signInIntent);
            finish();

        } else {

            welcomeLbl.setText("You are logged in!");
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSearch:
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            case R.id.btnSignout:
                mAuth.signOut();
                Intent signInIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(signInIntent);
                finish();
        }
    }
}
```

My Sign out button's case works because it signs out and navigate back to Sign In activity as expected, but button Search does the same, whereas it should navigate to Search Activity.

Here is my Search Activity :

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText searchField;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchField);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding breaks to switch options statements, if you don't add breaks the code will continue to execute as a [fall through](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), when you want one option to execute the actions of another option.

```
case R.id.btnSearch:
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.btnSignout:
            mAuth.signOut();
            Intent signInIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(signInIntent);
            finish();
            break;
```